# How to write jsonb inside WHERE without JSON Processing Functions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, postgresql-json

This is my `query` and it works. I store the list of dictionaries inside my `jsonb` column.

```
SELECT
    items.title
FROM
    items
WHERE
    jsonb_path_exists(items.types::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.target == "discount")')
```

Is there any way to write this without `jsonb_path_exists()` function?

Also, do JSON Processing Functions use indexing?

I want to simplify the readability/look of my query because it is so long. And curious if I can get any performance improvements by not using JSON Processing Functions.

I tried to replace it with `@?` but failed. [This is what I used (quote from PostgreSQL)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html):

> jsonb @? jsonpath → boolean
>
> Does JSON path return any item for the specified JSON value?
>
> '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @? '$.a[*] ? (@ > 2)' → t

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: "*Do JSON Processing Functions use indexing?*" - the page you quoted also writes that "[Section 8.14.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)  describes how these operators can be used to effectively search indexed jsonb data".

Comment: "*I tried to replace it with `@?` but failed*" - please also show us the query you tried. How did it fail?

Comment: Why are you casting the column to `jsonb` to begin with? If it's defined as `jsonb` the cast is useless (and you can shorten your query by removing it). If it's `json` (or even worse `text`)  then you should convert it to `jsonb` so that you don't need the cast everywhere and indexes are easier to define (and use)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation of the JSON path is a bit different between the `jsonb_path_xxx()` functions and the equivalent operator. Most importantly you do not need the `? (...)` condition as that is implied when using the operator.

The following should be equivalent:

```
where items.types::jsonb @? '$[*].target == "discount"'
```

---

If you want to simplify or shorten your query, introduce an alias for `items` so that you don't need to repeat the complete table name everywhere. Converting the column `types` to `jsonb` would further simplify your query as you don't need the cast anymore.

---

> And curious if I can get any performance improvements by not using JSON Processing Functions.

The `@?` operator can make use [of a GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE) - but this only works for `jsonb` not for the `json` data type.

The above where condition could make use of the following index:

```
create index on items using gin ( (types::jsonb) );
```

The index definition could be simplified by removing the cast, if the column was correctly defined as `jsonb`.